# How to set the baseline skip of the document main font

Tags: line-spacing

I am using the below mentioned command to change the document main font. But I am unable to control the  `\baselineskip` value zero.

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
\@setfontsize\normalsize{9.5pt}{11.5pt}% 
  \abovedisplayskip 8pt plus2pt minus4pt%
  \belowdisplayskip\abovedisplayskip%
  \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ plus3pt%
  \belowdisplayshortskip 5pt plus3pt minus3pt%
  \let\@listi\@listI%
}
```

My output and problem below mentioned here.

[image]

Comment: i'm not sure i completely understand the question, but from the attached graphic, it looks like you want the text to end up flush at the bottom of the page.  for this to happen, on a page that contains only text, the value of `\textheight` must be calculated as one "short line" (the height of the tallest letter or parenthesis in the font) plus an integer multiple of the `\baselineskip`.  since you haven't said what document class and font you use, it's impossible to make that calculation.

Comment: Are you using `geometry` for setting the page parameters?

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be thinking `\baselineskip` refers to the bottom of the page, it does not: it refers to the separation of each line of text, you set it in that code to 11.5pt.

To make sure that the bottom line is flush with the bottom of the page you need `\flushbottom` and you need `\textheight` - `\topskip` to be an integer multiple
of `\baselineskip` so that a page with just text has an exact number of lines.

Comment: @carlisle 56 lines per page. But I don't know how to execute the concept through the TeX coding. Kindly advice

Comment: `\normalbaselineskip=11.5pt \textheight=\dimexpr 56\normalbaselineskip+\topskip\relax`

Comment: @carlisle \baselineskip is working in this code but topskip is not relaxed. The same space will be taken top of the text. The footer is slightly affected.

Comment: @Vetri sorry I can not guess what you mean by "\topskip is not relaxed" `\topskip` is a length it can not be `\relax` It is the position of the first baseline on the page.